# Spark SQL window function causes skew in data distribution

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The performance of this Spark SQL query is bad due to skew data distribution:

```
select c.*, coalesce(
      sum(revenue)
        OVER (PARTITION BY cid, pid, code
        ORDER BY (cTime div (1000*3600))
        RANGE BETWEEN 336 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING), 0L) as totalRevenue
  from records c
```

I see in SparkUI that single task stack and the cluster fail if I increase the scanned range.

I am using Yarn at AWS EMR, with Spark 2.2.0

How can I overcome this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add information about the failure? Presumably it is an OutOfMemeoryError?

Comment: ExecutorLostFailure (executor 8 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 21.8 GB of 21.7 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

Comment: Can you count the number of rows per every `cid`, `pid` and `code`? Could you share the execution plan? What's the version of Spark? Is this YARN? Add the entire stack trace in your question. Add all the answers to your question (edit it and add what I asked for). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @JacekLaskowski , I add versions. I can see by tasks duration and eventually the files sizes (I write to files at the end) that one combination of pid, cid, code is significantly larger the the others. Omitting them will improve the performance, but I can't do it in production.

Comment: Thanks @EdKohlwey can you please provide a clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only recommend several approaches to alleviate your condition for investigation. I would actually try two approaches that don’t treat the skew first:

- Try increasing the executor memory per the message. On YARN you may additionally need to increase the maximum container memory as well. The default on Spark IIRC is 2gb and its not uncommon to need to increase it.
- Try switching to memory_and_disk or disk_only persistence levels. I believe this should work for your query although it can be hard to eyeball the full query plan

The reason for this is that at least to my eye your data is fundamentally skewed. You’re setting yourself up for maintenance difficulties if you start reshaping the data to address the skew in specific ways to the current shape of the data because the shape of the data may change over time. In my opinion at least you want to preserve the most straightforward implementation of your query for as long as you can, and only optimize skew issues programmatically if you hit problems with SLA violations, etc.

If those don’t work then you can try to address the skew directly. <s>A simple approach for this is to create a third column that is populated by a random number for the column values that are known to be problematic. Do one pass of your summing operation with this in place, using it as a key, then a second pass with the extra random column removed. Alternatively you can do two queries and concatenate them: one with the random number for skewed data (which must still be handled in two passes) and another unaltered query for the non problematic data.</s>

**Edit - compute partial sums through two frames**

The fundamentally useful observation here is that addition is commutative and associative. My original proposal based on random numbers won't work but this will. Basically, you want to compute the partial sum of the frame you want in several parts. The easiest way to do this is probably as a set of ranges (two used here for simplicity):

```
create temporary table partial_revenue_1 as select c.*, coalesce(
      sum(revenue)
        OVER (PARTITION BY cid, pid, code
        ORDER BY (cTime div (1000*3600))
        RANGE BETWEEN 336 PRECEDING and 118 PRECEDING), 0L) as partialTotalRevenue
  from records c

create temporary table partial_revenue_2 as select c.*, coalesce(
      sum(revenue)
        OVER (PARTITION BY cid, pid, code
        ORDER BY (cTime div (1000*3600))
        RANGE BETWEEN 117 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING), 0L) as partialTotalRevenue
  from records c

create temporary table combined_partials as select * from
    partial_reveneue_1 union all select * from partial_revenue_2

select sum(partialTotalRevenue), first(c.some_col) ... from 
    combined_partials c group by cid, pid, code
```

Notice you need to use the `first` aggregate function to cull the duplicate fields that you will have from the earlier `select *` operations on the `records` table. Don't worry, this will be fine since both values came from the same table.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I will focus on solving the skew problem for now. 
Can you please what you mead "third" column?  Maybe a small example

Comment: LeonB cool. Do you understand the approach I outlined for doing so? Does it require further clarification?

Comment: I will appreciate more clarification. Thanks

Comment: For the second pass should I use reduceByKey since it works locally first and then shuffle, otherwise I will face the same problem?

Comment: summing using random column will interfere with window function so relevant key will separate.

Comment: You're right - the usual "random number" trick won't work in window functions. I think computing partial sums over a range will. I've outlined this approach in the revised answer.

Comment: Thanks @EdKohlwey . Still I think that separating and combine won't be correct. Since one combination will be on one window and it matched will be on other. Each of them will have 0, summing will produce 0 when the correct is 1.

Comment: Why would they each have 0? Whatever rows contribute to the sum have to be somewhere in one of those two ranges.

Comment: Ok I got it now, the row is really should be in some window.
Still: 
1) The strength of window function is that all other fields remain (what is not in the group by), here I will loose them ( the first will take the first only)
2)  Doing group by on skew keys will cause the same problem